# Wordpress & PHP - get_currentuserinfo();

Tags: php, wordpress

I have searched to the end of the internet and can't seem to find anything that helps me with my issue. I have a wordpress site (inherited) and I simply want to be able to obtain a user's information when they're logged in. From the documentation I see to use get_currentuserinfo() but when I try to use it I get nothing.

The file resides in a folder in my main html directory. Here are the contents:

```
<?php 
include_once("../wp-includes/pluggable.php"); 
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  echo $current_user->user_login;


?>
```

I'm literally losing my mind over this. Is there something else I need to include at the top? Do I have to create the page within wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must include `wp-load.php` to use wordpress function in php file outside wordpress

```
require_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  echo $current_user->user_login;
```

Comment: I don't seem to have a "wp-load.php" file. Can I just locate this and add it anywhere?

Comment: I finally found the file and everything works now. Thanks Dinesh!

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE**: if you're calling get_currentuserinfo() at the time the plugin loads, which won't work because it's not defined yet. that particular function is defined inside pluggable.php, which load after the plugins load. so your problem may lies therein.so please check in your pluggable.php
>
> you can also use **"wp_get_current_user();"** instead "get_currentuserinfo();". ways to use "wp_get_current_user();" is mention below.[for more reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
/**
 * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
 *     return;
 */
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```